# How to deserialise json string in C# using JavascriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to get value of label from following string.
I have a string in this format.

```
var string = "[{\"key\":\"182\",\"label\":\"testinstitution\"}]"

dynamic dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(string);

string inst = dict["label"]; //This is not working
```

I am getting dict in form of key value pair object but I am not able to get value of label. I cannot use JSON.NET.

Comment: 1-Do you receive any error when deserializing? 2-To access a "property" of the dynamic object call it by it's name: `string inst = dict.label;` 3-your JSON definition is an array, so it should be `string inst = dict[0].label;` 4-If you know the exact structure, use a concrete class instead of dynamic, it's more efficient.

Comment: If I inspect then I see dict in this form. dict[0] [0] key "key" value "182" [1] key "label" value "testinstitution" . The dict[0].label is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve value of label from your string use `string inst = dict[0]["label"];`.

## Explanation

The reason why you need additional `[0]` is because deserialization returns **array of key value pairs**. First object from that array will go to index `[0]`, second object from array to index `[1]` an so on. Your string has array of only one object. Here is an example of when you have two objects, where second object has another object inside of it, in which case you would have to write 
`dict[1]["foo"]["two"]` to get to desired value:

```
var myString = @"
  [
    {
      'one': '1'
    },
    {
      'foo': 
      {
        'two': '2'
      }
    }
  ]";
dynamic dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(myString);
string inst = dict[1]["foo"]["two"];
```

## Additional FYI

If you know structure of your data consider using strong types (as suggested in one of the comments). Here is example of how you would do it:

```
public class Data
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myString = @"
                [{
                    'key': 182,
                    'label': 'testinstitution'
                }]";
        List<Data> dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Data>>(myString);
        foreach (var d in dict)
            Console.WriteLine(d.key + " " + d.label);

        Console.ReadKey();            
    }
}
```

Note that properties `key` and `value` in your `Data` object much match names of those in your array of objects exactly.